# release code error but not in debug or on source

Tags: r, debugging, package, raster

My code runs fine but fails in a package

I boiled it down to

```
wtf<-function(r)
{
    require(raster)
    stopifnot(class(r) == "RasterLayer")
    return(as.matrix(r))
}
```

When sourced, everything works fine. When the function is part of a package, it fails. It nicely runs in debug mode though, step by step.

```
 library(mypackage)
 r <- raster(ncol=6, nrow=6)
 r[] <- runif(ncell(r),0,1)
 extent(r) <- matrix(c(0, 0, 6, 6), nrow=2)

 wtf(r)

 # Error in as.vector(data) :
 # no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

 # Traceback
 # 5 as.vector(data)          
 # 4 array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x), 
 #    NULL) else NULL) 
 # 3 as.matrix.default(r) 
 # 2 as.matrix(r) at terrain.R#7
 # 1 wtf(s)
```

I'm a bit puzzeled as to why this happens and to how proceed. 
The build went fine, the check went clean, so what is going on?

What would be the next question to ask and explore in order to solve the problem?

```
 R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
 Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

 locale:
 [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
 [1] raster_2.3-0  spdep_0.5-77  Matrix_1.1-4  minerva_1.4.1 gdata_2.13.3 rgdal_0.9-1   sp_1.0-15    

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] boot_1.3-11     coda_0.16-1     deldir_0.1-5    grid_3.1.1      gtools_3.4.1  lattice_0.20-29 LearnBayes_2.15 MASS_7.3-33     nlme_3.1-118    parallel_3.1.1  splines_3.1.1   tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: Is the `raster` package actually being loaded?

Comment: @john, the package loads it upon package load. Things don't change if I use 'library(raster)' instead

Comment: @Jan - When you say "the package loads it upon package load" do you mean it's listed as a depends/imports in your NAMESPACE file? Or are you just referring to the call to "require".  Note you shouldn't have to make a call to require like that in package code.

Comment: @Dason sorry I was unclear. mypackage depends on raster, so raster is loaded when library(mypackage) is issued. Only reason I put 'require' in the function is that you guys can see that the function acts on a raster layer and that raster package has been loaded. My bad. According to ´sessionInfo()´ raster was loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback shows that the default as.matrix is used, rather than the raster variant. I believe this problem goes away if you add this line to your Namespace file:

```
import(raster)
```

Or when you are explicit about which as.matrix you want:

```
wtf <- function(r) {
    stopifnot(inherits(r, "RasterLayer"))
    raster::as.matrix(r)
}
```

Rather than 'manually' testing for class membership, you might consider a more formal (S4) approach:

```
if (!isGeneric("wtf")) {
    setGeneric("wtf", function(x, ...)
        standardGeneric("wtf"))
}   

setMethod("wtf", signature(x='RasterLayer'), 
    function(x, ...)  {
        raster::as.matrix(x)
    }
)
```

Comment: Most instructive, @RobertH. From that I assume that the functions namespace did not know all the methods for `raster`. Is that normal behavior or is something fishy in `raster`? Do you mind speculating.